# WebView Click Action

Tags: android

I am Working on Android on a simple app .And i am new to Android . I have small task on WebView.I am adding a HTML page to Webview .And its working fine .And the problem is how to give the click action to "Click Button " which is the type of the colored text in HTML page.

If i am used the click Action in my javascrip how i able to get that click Action in My Intent.

Comment: Use javascript in your html page

Comment: i am new to Android ..,can you send any sample.

Comment: @Shalini Can you gove any documentation on this

Comment: sorry dont know about that more

Comment: Finally i got the Result Thank you
Using js i got the Action on Intent
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonclickAction(toast) {
 
        Android.showToast(toast);
  
    }
</script>
Using mwebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    mwebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");//in js add this fn


   <script type="text/javascript">
         function buttonclickAction(toast) {
                Android.showToast(toast);           
         }   
    </script>
```